# importing merged cells of xls file to MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, import, merge

I have some xls files, which they all have merged cells in specific columns. so when I use xlsread, the data of that column is read as NaN.
for example when my data is:

```
1   2   2   5
3   1   2   1
2   4   2   3
```

if the last column be the merging result of 4th and 5th columns, when I use xlsread the output will be:

```
1   2   2   NaN
3   1   2   NaN
2   4   2   NaN
```

For my real data, it is time consuming to unmerge columns in excel before importing. how can I import them to MATLAB in the merged format?

Comment: This question may be better suited to Super User or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=matlab

Comment: I think that group is dealing the problems only regarding mathematica @ashleedawg

Comment: The merged cells are being read as strings not at numeric data.  You'll find them in the 2nd output of `xlsread`.  You may also be interested in the 3rd output, which contains both numeric and string data.

Comment: @parisa - did you click the link and see the 900 matlab posts including a few almost identical to yours?  Or, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269057/370758) and other meta discussions, a better place for this type of question is [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=matlab) (700 questions just at that link). More importantly, **have you read this @ [help/on-topic]?** Which category is *"How to import numbers into Matlab?"*: a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or a commonly used programmer's tool? **Is it a problem *unique* to software development?**

Comment: @ashleedawg, if this question isn't suitable here then neither are a large majority of the questions with the `MATLAB` tag.  IMHO it is suitable here, although could be improved by showing some code.  None the less, the question is pretty clear to anyone who's loaded spreadsheet data into MATLAB.

Comment: @parisa: have you tried reading the sheet as string and then convert after imported to matlab?

Comment: @ashleedawg: the OP's question does require knowledge of matlab functions and reading excel sheets with merged cells to matlab seems like a common situation -- common enough to be potentially helpful to more SO users. The example you raised is a unique question regarding the Matlab command interface. Think of any other programming languages, if a question pertains to the particular behavior of a function/routine/method that is in the base language, wouldn't you think it is a part of the typical SO questions?

Comment: @ashleedawg mathematica.stackexchange.com is for questions about [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). All the questions there with the [matlab] tag are about how to use MATLAB *with* Mathematica, or how to exchange data between the two. This question has nothing to do with Mathematica and would be off-topic for that site.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger.  I have no opinion; I was just quoting the FAQ and Meta discussions. Not a big deal either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested saving some Excel 2013 sheets with numbers in merged cells, in either .xlsx or .xls format, and then reading them into MATLAB R2016b with `xlsread` and the numbers are read correctly. So either your version(s) behave differently or, as noted in Phil Goddard's comment, the values in the merged cells are formatted as text in Excel.

As Phil says, if you use the syntax

```
[num, txt, both] = xlsread('myfile.xls')
```

the result will be a numeric matrix `num` containing **only** the cell values that are numbers, a cell array `txt` containing **only** the cell values that are text, and a cell array `both` containing the values of all the cells as either numbers or character vectors as appropriate. If you have columns or rows containing mixed numbers and text, the text cells will return `NaN` values in `num`.

Comment: I tried another xls file with merged cells, and as you mentioned, it reads the numbers correctly and another column as NaN. thanks, although I couldn't find the problem of the first file.

Comment: Oops, my example used `all` as a variable name but that's the name of a builtin function. Don't do this! Now corrected.